# Input Size for UNet3D

Tags: torch, unet-neural-network

First and foremost, I want to precise that I am a begginer in torch. I am struggling with the following code (found on github), I want to know what should be the input size of a such UNet.

```
"""Adapted from https://github.com/milesial/Pytorch-UNet/tree/master/unet"""
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels, n_classes, width_multiplier=1, trilinear=True, use_ds_conv=False):
        """A simple 3D Unet, adapted from a 2D Unet from https://github.com/milesial/Pytorch-UNet/tree/master/unet
        Arguments:
          n_channels = number of input channels; 3 for RGB, 1 for grayscale input
          n_classes = number of output channels/classes
          width_multiplier = how much 'wider' your UNet should be compared with a standard UNet
                  default is 1;, meaning 32 -> 64 -> 128 -> 256 -> 512 -> 256 -> 128 -> 64 -> 32
                  higher values increase the number of kernels pay layer, by that factor
          trilinear = use trilinear interpolation to upsample; if false, 3D convtranspose layers will be used instead
          use_ds_conv = if True, we use depthwise-separable convolutional layers. in my experience, this is of little help. This
                  appears to be because with 3D data, the vast vast majority of GPU RAM is the input data/labels, not the params, so little
                  VRAM is saved by using ds_conv, and yet performance suffers."""
        super(UNet, self).__init__()
        _channels = (32, 64, 128, 256, 512)
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.channels = [int(c*width_multiplier) for c in _channels]
        self.trilinear = trilinear
        self.convtype = DepthwiseSeparableConv3d if use_ds_conv else nn.Conv3d

        self.inc = DoubleConv(n_channels, self.channels[0], conv_type=self.convtype)
        self.down1 = Down(self.channels[0], self.channels[1], conv_type=self.convtype)
        self.down2 = Down(self.channels[1], self.channels[2], conv_type=self.convtype)
        self.down3 = Down(self.channels[2], self.channels[3], conv_type=self.convtype)
        factor = 2 if trilinear else 1
        self.down4 = Down(self.channels[3], self.channels[4] // factor, conv_type=self.convtype)
        self.up1 = Up(self.channels[4], self.channels[3] // factor, trilinear)
        self.up2 = Up(self.channels[3], self.channels[2] // factor, trilinear)
        self.up3 = Up(self.channels[2], self.channels[1] // factor, trilinear)
        self.up4 = Up(self.channels[1], self.channels[0], trilinear)
        self.outc = OutConv(self.channels[0], n_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.inc(x)
        x2 = self.down1(x1)
        x3 = self.down2(x2)
        x4 = self.down3(x3)
        x5 = self.down4(x4)
        x = self.up1(x5, x4)
        x = self.up2(x, x3)
        x = self.up3(x, x2)
        x = self.up4(x, x1)
        logits = self.outc(x)
        return logits


class DoubleConv(nn.Module):
    """(convolution => [BN] => ReLU) * 2"""

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, conv_type=nn.Conv3d, mid_channels=None):
        super().__init__()
        if not mid_channels:
            mid_channels = out_channels
        self.double_conv = nn.Sequential(
            conv_type(in_channels, mid_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(mid_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            conv_type(mid_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.double_conv(x)


class Down(nn.Module):
    """Downscaling with maxpool then double conv"""

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, conv_type=nn.Conv3d):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxpool_conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxPool3d(2),
            DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels, conv_type=conv_type)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.maxpool_conv(x)


class Up(nn.Module):
    """Upscaling then double conv"""

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, trilinear=True):
        super().__init__()

        # if trilinear, use the normal convolutions to reduce the number of channels
        if trilinear:
            self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='trilinear', align_corners=True)
            self.conv = DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels, mid_channels=in_channels // 2)
        else:
            self.up = nn.ConvTranspose3d(in_channels, in_channels // 2, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
            self.conv = DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels)


    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.up(x1)
        # input is CHW
        diffY = x2.size()[2] - x1.size()[2]
        diffX = x2.size()[3] - x1.size()[3]

        x1 = F.pad(x1, [diffX // 2, diffX - diffX // 2,
                        diffY // 2, diffY - diffY // 2])
        # if you have padding issues, see
        # https://github.com/HaiyongJiang/U-Net-Pytorch-Unstructured-Buggy/commit/0e854509c2cea854e247a9c615f175f76fbb2e3a
        # https://github.com/xiaopeng-liao/Pytorch-UNet/commit/8ebac70e633bac59fc22bb5195e513d5832fb3bd
        x = torch.cat([x2, x1], dim=1)
        return self.conv(x)


class OutConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(OutConv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv3d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)


class DepthwiseSeparableConv3d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nin, nout, kernel_size, padding, kernels_per_layer=1):
        super(DepthwiseSeparableConv3d, self).__init__()
        self.depthwise = nn.Conv3d(nin, nin * kernels_per_layer, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=padding, groups=nin)
        self.pointwise = nn.Conv3d(nin * kernels_per_layer, nout, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.depthwise(x)
        out = self.pointwise(out)
        return out
```

The Unet can simply be built with the following command:

`model = UNet(n_channels, n_classes, width_multiplier=1, trilinear=True, use_ds_conv=False)`

Thank very much beforehand!

PS: The code can be found [here](https://github.com/jphdotam/Unet3D)

I have tested a lot of input with different size with no result until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see the `forward` function under the `UNet` class.

```
def forward(self, x):
    x1 = self.inc(x)
    x2 = self.down1(x1)
    x3 = self.down2(x2)
    x4 = self.down3(x3)
    x5 = self.down4(x4)
    x = self.up1(x5, x4)
    x = self.up2(x, x3)
    x = self.up3(x, x2)
    x = self.up4(x, x1)
    logits = self.outc(x)
    return logits
```

We observe that this 3D U-Net employs the `self.down` module four times. To gain insight, we navigate to the `self.down` module declared within the `__init__` function.

```
self.down1 = Down(self.channels[0], self.channels[1], conv_type=self.convtype)
self.down2 = Down(self.channels[1], self.channels[2], conv_type=self.convtype)
self.down3 = Down(self.channels[2], self.channels[3], conv_type=self.convtype)
factor = 2 if trilinear else 1
self.down4 = Down(self.channels[3], self.channels[4] // factor, conv_type=self.convtype)
```

We can find that all of the `self.down` module use `Down` class.

```
class Down(nn.Module):
"""Downscaling with maxpool then double conv"""

def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, conv_type=nn.Conv3d):
    super().__init__()
    self.maxpool_conv = nn.Sequential(
        nn.MaxPool3d(2),
        DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels, conv_type=conv_type)
    )

def forward(self, x):
    return self.maxpool_conv(x)
```

Here, `nn.MaxPool3d(2)` represents the 3D max-pooling layer, which reduce the input image size by half. For instance, if your input image size is 256 × 256 × 256, it becomes 128 × 128 × 128 after passing through the 3D max-pooling layers.

Given the 3D U-Net architecture, which employs 4 sets of 3D max-pooling layers, the input size should be multiples of 2^4. For example, an input size of 256 × 128 × 64 is acceptable since all dimensions can be divided by 2^4. However, an input size of 72 × 128 × 36 would result in an error because 72 and 36 are not divisible by 2^4.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! Do you know I could I modify it to allow input/out tensors to be of shape (1,1,8 or 4, 64,64) for example ? Thank you again @CHIH-HAO LIU :)

Comment: In typical U-Net model, the input tensor dimension  is equal to the output tensor dimension. The tensor size is (Batch size, channel, height, width), so the height and width must be divisible by 2^4.